# how can i make my @Html.ValidationMessageFor work with integer value

Tags: vb.net, model-view-controller, integer

How can i change this towards working with a integer/int64 value ?

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(Function(model) model.Prijs, htmlAttributes:=New With {.class = "control-label col-md-2"})
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(Function(model) model.Prijs, New With {.htmlAttributes = New With {.class = "form-control"}})
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.Prijs, "", New With {.class = "text-danger"})
        </div>
    </div>
```

with the little knowledge  i have i think i need to change the "" towards something that can capture an integer value ?

Answer (score -1):

after test alot i found out i forget to add prijs to my create & edit function

```
 Function Edit(<Bind(Include:="Id,Soort,TransactieType,Beschrijving,Locatie,prijs")
```